# continuous time markov chain sample size

Tags: sample-size, markov-process

Is that the same if I have one patient with one Markov chain of length 100, and 50 patients with 50 Markov chains of length 2?

If they are the same, why?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely not the same. If patients are sampled from the stationary distribution it is better, but still not the same.

Comment: It depends on your assumptions and model.  The main problem with the 50-patient version is that you have no replicated transitions for any patient and therefore have no way to check whether the transitions act similarly from one patient to another.  The main problem with the one-patient version is that you have almost no basis to generalize your observations to any other patients because you have no replicated patients.